# Create a line renderer with speed from Point A to Point B?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I create a line renderer with speed that moves from Point A to Point B?

```
public GameObject gameObject1;          // Reference to the first GameObject
     public GameObject gameObject2;          // Reference to the second GameObject

     private LineRenderer line;                           // Line Renderer

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         // Add a Line Renderer to the GameObject
         line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
         // Set the width of the Line Renderer
         line.SetWidth(0.0012F, 0.0012F);
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
        line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(gameObject1.transform.position.x,gameObject1.transform.position.y,gameObject1.transform.position.z));
        line.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(gameObject2.transform.position.x,gameObject2.transform.position.y,gameObject2.transform.position.z));
     }
```

Comment: Try to make an extra vector that you move from point a to point b with a speed and make the linerender have that as end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g. (assuming the two objects do not change their position meanwhile)

```
// in seconds
public float duration = 1;

private bool isDoingLine;

private void Start()
{
    // Add a Line Renderer to the GameObject
     line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
     // Set the width of the Line Renderer
     line.SetWidth(0.0012F, 0.0012F);
     line.positionCount = 2;
     line.SetPosition(0, gameObject1.transform.position);
     line.SetPosition(1, gameObject1.transform.position);

     DoLine();
}

public void DoLine()
{
    if(!isDoingLine) StartCoroutine(LineRoutine());
}

IEnumerator LineRoutine() 
{
     isDoingLine = true;

     line.SetPosition(0, gameObject1.transform.position);

     var timePassed = 0f;
     while(timePassed < duration)
     {
         var factor = timePassed / duration;
         // optionally add ease-in ease-out
         //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

         line.SetPosition(1, Vector3.Lerp(gameObject1.transform.position, gameObject2.transform.position, factor));

         timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, duration - timePassed);
         yield return null;
     }

     // when done just in case set the final position fix
     line.SetPosition(1, gameObject2.transform.position);

     isDoingLine = false;
 }
```

using [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to interpolate between the two positions.

There is really no need btw to go through `new Vector3` here. `Vector3` is a `struct` so any assignment or parameter pass uses a copy anyway.

Comment: Thank you I removed the ```line.SetPosition(1, gameObject2.transform.position);``` and it works as expected :)

Comment: If i have to reset the time again what do I have to do? Which attribute should i change?